# Origin to geometry does same thing as geometry to origin

Tags: geometry, origin

Anyone else got this same problem?

I got this tower of blocks which with I wanna do some collision stuff and I try to set each block to have its own origin/center, but when I do "Origin to geometry" it instead moves all blocks to origin point that they all have from original block which I multiplied with Array modifiers to make this tower...

"Origin to geometry" worked just day before, anyone got any idea what is causing this not to work? ...

Edit: Here's the .blend file. Thank you!

Edit2: Filename too long which derps the site (for me) and I can't download it, so here's better download link with shorter file .blend name:

[image]

Comment: Are these blocks children of another object or do they still have modifiers? Is each block a separate mesh or are they still one object with array modifier?

Comment: Could you provide a .blend file on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to be able to help you?

Comment: They are separate meshes, they have no modifiers on them and none of them are parented to anything (or child of anything). Sorry I should have known to provide .blend file, I'll provide it next time I am on my computer (within 7-12 hours.) sorry and thank you!

Comment: Edited/added link to .blend file to question.

Comment: As you use rigid body simulation, move the timeline to the 1-st frame as for now it's on the 2-nd. Do any changes with objects while on the 1-st keyframe.

Comment: It's that simple thing?!? :D Well damn...... Thank you so much! Dude, make an answer, I'll mark it as correct one!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue as well, with a rigid body world activated.  I had to either move to frame 0 and then set the origin, or I could uncheck the rigid body world and then set the origin, or I could adjust the simulation start of the rigid body world to the same frame as the frame start in my output properties- and then set the origin.

Don't know why the rigid body system does this to the objects but at least there's a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just recently and the culprit seems to be "Rigid Body World" as mentioned by Max Appian.

If "Rigid Body World" is ON and objects are created using the array modifier, attempting to "Set Origin to Geometry" causes the spawned objects to relocate to the spawner object. The origin is not set. This is after separating the spawned objects.

The only way I could get the Set Origin to work properly was to temporarily turn off Rigid Body World. Then everything works as expected (don't forget to turn Rigid Body World back on, of course).